# Dotted line in stat_chull - R

Tags: r

I am trying to change the convex hull line type to dotted in this code:

```
# from https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_chull.html
data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)

ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg", color = "cyl")+
  stat_chull(aes(color = cyl, fill = cyl), alpha = 0.1, geom = "polygon")
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `linetype = "dotted"` to  `stat_chull`.

```r
library(ggpubr)

data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)

ggscatter(df, x = "wt", y = "mpg", color = "cyl")+
  stat_chull(aes(color = cyl, fill = cyl), alpha = 0.1, geom = "polygon", linetype = "dotted")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>